# Doctrine DBAL Include Issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing below issue after loading Doctrine DBAL classes

```
use Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader;

require 'vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine', 'vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine');
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
```

**Output:**

**Fatal error:**

> Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration' not found

Comment: In most cases it's easier to use "composer require doctrine/dbal" and "require vendor/autoload.php".  The Doctrine classloader is somewhat depreciated and not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to load like composer does:

```
$classLoader = new ClassLoader('Doctrine\DBAL', 'vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib');
```

Comment: thanks.. i have used composer and included autoload.php, it works fine.

Comment: Nice, this is the way to go. I had to use this autoloader in a project where I didn't need all the libs I had on composer for this single script, so this is a solution for this specific case.